# Why is my new server not letting me connect?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server

I followed the Minecraft wiki on how to set up a new server (extract zip, add name to admin file and run). However, when I connect through the local client to the server using `127.0.0.1` as my IP (localhost) the local client freezes, and the server reports `Kicking /127.0.0.1: You need to log in!`.

But since I was using the local client, I had logged in and I have in fact bought the game. Whats going on? How do I fix this? I am also running the latest version of Java.

Server console log:

> ```
>  14:15:10  Setting up
>  14:15:10  Loading level
>  14:15:10  Now accepting input on 25565
>  14:15:10  Level saved! Load: 0/16
>  14:15:19  /127.0.0.1 connected
>  14:15:24  Kicking /127.0.0.1: You need to log in!
>  14:15:24  /127.0.0.1 disconnected
> ```

Comment: Can the server connect to minecraft.net?

Comment: it needs to do that? How can I tell if it can talk to minecraft.net?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your server needs to connect to minecraft.net so it can verify that everyone who connects has a legitimate and unhacked version of the game.  You can test this by using the `ping minecraft.net` command from the Command Prompt.

However, another option which would open your server up to hackers is to turn off the authentication.  In your server configuration file, just add the line `online-mode=false` and you should have no problems connecting then.  However, any hackers could join your server and wreak havoc so be warned.

**ADDITION**

If that doesn't work for you, ensure that you have the correct `minecraft_server.jar` file.  The correct one can be found ate the bottom of the [Minecraft Downloads](http://www.minecraft.net/download.jsp) page.  The one on the servers page is often out of date.

Comment: I've tried pinging this which worked fine. I also disabled my firewalls and it still made no difference. Also, adding the online-mode = false didn't make a difference either.

Comment: You probably downloaded the `minecraft-server.jar` file on the Servers page of the Minecraft website, rather than the `minecraft_server.jar` file on the Downloads page of the website.  Check my edit for a link to the proper page.

Comment: Thank you so much! That works now! They really should remove the servers page :)